# Is it good practice to use `fwrite` within loops?

Tags: c, fwrite, stdio

I need to write an array whose parts are scattered in code.

In short, my code is this:

```
(...)
FILE *f = fopen(filepath, "wb"); // wb -write binary

for (uint i = 0; i < num_points; i++) {
    fwrite(points[i].loc, sizeof(float[3]), 1, f);
}

fclose(f);
```

As you can see, my solution was writing each new part of the array in front of the file.

But does this have a problem with efficiency, or memory reading? Should I allocate the entire array in RAM and then write the file?

Comment: `fwrite` handles the buffering for you.

Comment: Aside: `unsigned`, IMO, is a better practice than `uint`.

Comment: It's rather `sizeof(float)` instead of `sizeof(float[3])`, assuming the type of `points[i].loc` __is__ `float`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fwrite` will buffer your data until its buffer is full, or `fflush`/`fclose`/etc. is called. So it won't perform a syscall each iteration.

Comment: Nice. I'm glad to hear that :)